# Alias a template function with default parameters

Tags: c++, templates, default-arguments

The following C++ code does not compile:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void f(int, bool = true);

void g()
{
    auto h = f<int>;
    h(1); // error: too few arguments to function
}
```

Instead, I have to call `h` with the 2nd parameter:

```cpp
h(1, true);
```

Why doesn't `h(1)` work?

Is there a simple way to alias a template function to bind the template argument while keeping the default function argument?

Comment: Aliases only work on types. Default parameter values are not part of a function's signature, so they can't be preserved through a type alias.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`h` is declared as function pointer, unfortunately it can't specify [default arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments).

> Default arguments are only allowed in the parameter lists of function declarations `and lambda-expressions, (since C++11)` and are not allowed in the declarations of pointers to functions, references to functions, or in typedef declarations.

You can use a lambda wrapping `f` instead. E.g.

```
auto h = [](int i) { f<int>(i); };
h(1); // -> f<int>(1, true), using f's default argument
```

Or specify default argument on the lambda too.

```
auto h = [](int i, bool b = true) { f<int>(i, b); };
h(1);        // -> f<int>(1, true), using h, i.e. lambda's default argument
h(1, true);  // -> f<int>(1, true), not using default argument
h(1, false); // -> f<int>(1, false), not using default argument
```